# Match strings from one file on another file, extract an argument and populate a new column in the first file

Tags: regex, bash, awk

I have two files

**file1**

```
307201       00608670         5.70283
300048       fff0002a8        5.57004
300001       00608690         5.56917
300001       00608678         5.56917
150032       fff0002c8        2.78517
150028       fff0002c0        2.78509
150027       fff0002b8        2.78508
150024       fff0002d0        2.78502
```

---

**file2**

```
raw symbol [ 170]: GLO FUN : svma 0x00608690, sz  133  mem_mgr_init
rec(t) [ 170]:            val 0x00608690, sz  133  mem_mgr_init
raw symbol [ 171]: GLO OBJ : svma 0x0000608670, sz    8  angleCounter
rec(d) [ 171]:            val 0x0000608670, sz    8  angleCounter
raw symbol [ 172]: GLO FUN : svma 0x0000402e00, sz   16  th_signal_finished
rec(t) [ 172]:            val 0x0000402e00, sz   16  th_signal_finished
raw symbol [ 173]: GLO FUN : svma 0x0000403da0, sz  133  xlate_nl_inplace
rec(t) [ 173]:            val 0x0000403da0, sz  133  xlate_nl_inplace
raw symbol [ 174]: GLO FUN : svma 0x0000402eb0, sz   19  th_report_results
rec(t) [ 174]:            val 0x0000402eb0, sz   19  th_report_results
raw symbol [ 175]: GLO FUN : svma 0x0000400c40, sz   97  GetTestData
rec(t) [ 175]:            val 0x0000400c40, sz   97  GetTestData
raw symbol [ 176]: GLO FUN : svma 0x0000401d20, sz  144  al_exit
rec(t) [ 176]:            val 0x0000401d20, sz  144  al_exit
raw symbol [ 177]: GLO FUN : svma 0x0000000000, sz    0  fgetc@@GLIBC_2.2.5
```

I need to search each entry in column two of file1 in file two and find the associated symbol name($12 of file 2) and add this as the fourth column in file1. For entries not found, i need to mark it as NotFound. 
Desired output file is like this

```
307201       00608670         5.70283    angleCounter
300048       fff0002a8        5.57004    NotFound
300001       00608690         5.56917    mem_mgr_init
300001       00608678         5.56917    NotFound
150032       fff0002c8        2.78517    NotFound
150028       fff0002c0        2.78509    NotFound
150027       fff0002b8        2.78508    NotFound
150024       fff0002d0        2.78502    NotFound
```

I have used the below awk command, but that works partially. It prints each entry in the second column and its associated string from file2. However its not in the order of strings in the second column, bu the order at which each string appears in the second file.

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2];next} {for (i in a) if ($0 ~ i) {if ($12) print i"\t"$12;break;}}' file1 file2
```

Could someone help me?

Comment: Please format it properly before you start getting **Downvotes**.

Comment: I just add an small sample of formatting options so you can improve it

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat tst.awk               
NR==FNR {
    key = $(NF-3)
    gsub(/^0x0*|,$/,"",key)
    map[key] = $NF
    next
}
{
    key = $2
    sub(/^0+/,"",key)
    print $0, (key in map ? map[key] : "NotFound")
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file2 file1
307201       00608670         5.70283 angleCounter
300048       fff0002a8        5.57004 NotFound
300001       00608690         5.56917 mem_mgr_init
300001       00608678         5.56917 NotFound
150032       fff0002c8        2.78517 NotFound
150028       fff0002c0        2.78509 NotFound
150027       fff0002b8        2.78508 NotFound
150024       fff0002d0        2.78502 NotFound
```